# Can you only flash an image to a micro sd once? "error reading from storage. sd card may be broken."

Tags: sd-card, software-installation, image

so I'm facing an issue with the flashing process of the micro sd I'm using. I recently had the Raspbian OS installed on this card previously, but when messing around with the terminal attempting to create a *wifi bridge* to another device via ethernet cable. I accidentally altered the wifi interface in way which stopped it working all together. *So I decided to start from *scratch* and reformat sd card and flash a fresh image of Raspbian OS.* This is when I came across the problem.

This sd is a 64gb card, so I reformatted it to exFAT, as one does with card above 32gb. But now when I try flashing with Raspberry Pi Imager I see a message saying

"**error reading from storage. sd card may be broken**."

This couldn't possibly have damaged the sd card could it? I'm still able to add files to the card once its been reformatted after the failed flash perfectly fine. So what? I'm I now unable to use it for OS's now? but only for storage.

If anyone has come across this issue, or has any insight to this problem, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: no, you can flash it over again and again

Comment: And no need to reformat,  the flashing process overwrites all that anyway

Comment: Then what could be the reason for this error message while trying to flash the image on to the card.  its gets through the 100% and shows "error reading from storage. sd card may be broken." how can this be resolved for a successful flash?

Answer (score 1):

The SD card gets an image with initial partitions. Once the Pi boots, it uses the SD card just as any other disk: it reads and writes to it. So, an SD card can handle that it is written to multiple times.

Writing to the SD card is exactly what you do when you put the initial image on it. So, just multiple times writing to it should not be a problem.

That being said: SD cards have a limited number of times that you can write to them. But that is a 100 000 times or more, not a single image.

Comment: Then what could be the reason for this error message while trying to flash the image on to the card. its gets through the 100% and shows "error reading from storage. sd card may be broken." how can this be resolved for a successful flash?

Comment: It could be just a bad SD card. If you have a Linux system available, you can try a `dd if=/dev/<device_of_the_card> of=/dev/null`. If that runs successful, the card seems readable.

Comment: weird, this has happen to almost every sd card that I've used when trying to reflash it. 2 preloaded noob sd's and now this one. for a totally of three, i mean what are the odds have that?

Comment: So, how do you flash it? Is the card-reader that you use faulty?